# Start and end address in virtual memory of a process

Tags: c, linux, memory-management

I have a C program I have written and I am attempting to make a memory map of it.

How do I print to the screen the starting address and end address (within virtual memory) of the environment of the process.

The program is and always will be run on linux, not sure if that makes a difference, but it doesn't need any kind of portability.

I am looking for something that would preferably just give me a hexadecimal address of the start and end.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this example in C programming.

```
user@linux:~$ cat hello.c 
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
 printf("Hello World\n");
 getchar();
}
user@linux:~$ gcc hello.c -o hello
user@linux:~$ ./hello 
Hello World
```

Open another console to find out the process id (pid).
Run `ps` command as follows; Change `hello` with your program name.

In this case, the process id (pid) is `2011`

```
user@linux:~$ ps -ef | grep hello | grep -v grep
user      2011  1864  0 17:21 pts/2    00:00:00 ./hello
user@linux:~$
```

Then, check your `/proc/[pid]/maps` file with `cat` command

```
user@linux:~$ cat /proc/2011/maps | grep stack
bffeb000-c0000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
user@linux:~$
```

Alternatively, you can also use `pmap` command

```
user@linux:~$ pmap 2011 | grep stack
bffeb000     84K rw---    [ stack ]
user@linux:~$
```

In both cases, we can see that stack start at address `bffeb000`

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement i think you can get the memory map of a particular process if you know its PID. Use the command "**pmap**" for more info http://linux.die.net/man/1/pmap.

& if u want to print it in ur program then try to get pid with the help of function **getpid()**;
and then use **[system() call](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/system)** to execute the pmap command.

Comment: I have implemented that however I am not exactly sure what I am looking at. What exactly is the start and and address of the virtual memory used for my process?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply print out the content of the [`/proc/[PID]/maps`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) file where `[PID]` is the value of the process identifier of your process (call [`getpid()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html) to find out what this value is).

Comment: console output:

"sh: 1: /proc/7722/maps: Permission denied"

Comment: @mansonitefirefox you should read the content directly from your program. If you're neither root nor the same user running the program, you won't be able to read memory maps of other processes running under a different user (otherwise, this would be a huge security concern).

Comment: I am logged in as the user who wrote and is running the process.

Comment: logged in as root, still Permission denied

Comment: @mansonitefirefox double check whether you're (un)intentionally modifying any of the user identifiers such as suid and euid. The file's uid and gid must perfectly match up with your euid,egid,suid,and sgid. Also, check whether you're getting the correct pid.

Comment: Definitely just printing the value, no modifications. And I am using the correct pid because I used it successfully by using the pmap command (as suggested by another user), however that pmap is showing me a lot of information that doesn't seem relevant to my requirements.

Comment: @mansonitefirefox Tell us what you did. The error you get, "sh: 1: /proc/7722/maps: Permission denied" Means you did something strange. You should be able to run e.g `cat /proc/7722/maps` while your program is running. You could run that even in a terminal.